# adding an admin user to my web application asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Visual studio 2015 has a pre-built user registration/login page, I need to make an "admin" account that has access to an admin only page within the web app to enter in data to be stored to the database. I just dont know where to begin to add an account and give it write access. Would anyone happen to have knowledge on the pre-built registration and where I add an admin user and give them the ability to view a unique page but not let anyone else view it?

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2015 - In case of ASP.NET Web Page, you can use user id and its role during Page Load. If the Access Right is not valid, then return to Error Page.

In case of ASP.NET MVC, you can define Custom Attribute using `ActionFilterAttribute` in controller class `ActionResult` of the View.

Pre-built Registration works well for both Web Form and MVC Templates provided in VS 2015. For more information - please check AspNetUsers table in Sql Database created.

Please read more details [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)